# How to introduce a txt file inside the Latex file

Tags: pdftex

I have a txt file that says "A B C D..."

Now, I want to make a letex file that says "A=1, B=2, C=3..."

Could you teach me how to make this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.